# Adding components to a panel in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am using Eclipse for designing but the panel have a defined size and it won't take more components. I tried to make it scrollable and add more but nothing is working. If anyone knows how or has a better idea, please help.

[This is how it looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSXyG.png)

```
public class Makeup {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Makeup window = new Makeup();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Makeup() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 755, 660);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBackground(new Color(250, 240, 230));
        panel_2.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null,  null, null));
        panel_2.setBounds(100, 5, 555, 50);
        panel.add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Makeup Shop");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 555, 50);
        panel_2.add(lblNewLabel);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Edwardian Script ITC", Font.BOLD, 55));
        lblNewLabel.setBackground(new Color(250, 240, 230));
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(255, 105, 180));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setBackground(new Color(250, 240, 230));
        panel_3.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
        panel_3.setBounds(5, 65, 745, 35);
        panel.add(panel_3);
        panel_3.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Categories");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 745, 35);
        panel_3.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(new Color(255, 105, 180));
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Edwardian Script ITC", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
        panel_4.setBackground(new Color(255, 228, 225));
        panel_4.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        panel_4.setBounds(5, 105, 745, 30);
        panel.add(panel_4);
        panel_4.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel(" Lipstick & Lipgloss ");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBackground(new Color(255, 228, 225));
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(0, 0, 745, 30);
        panel_4.add(lblNewLabel_2);
        lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Edwardian Script ITC", Font.BOLD, 35));
        lblNewLabel_2.setForeground(new Color(255, 105, 180));
        lblNewLabel_2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(8, 140, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(198, 140, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(388, 140, 160, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_2);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(578, 140, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_3);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4.setBounds(8, 320, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4_1 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4_1.setBounds(198, 320, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4_2 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4_2.setBounds(388, 320, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4_2);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4_3 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4_3.setBounds(578, 320, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4_3);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4_4 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4_4.setBounds(8, 500, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4_4);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4_4_1 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4_4_1.setBounds(198, 500, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4_4_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4_4_2 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4_4_2.setBounds(388, 500, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4_4_2);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_4_4_3 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4_4_3.setBounds(578, 500, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_4_4_3);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_5.setBounds(8, 720, 170, 130);
        panel.add(btnNewButton_5);
        
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.PINK, 3));
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(250, 240, 230));
        panel_1.setBounds(757, 0, 500, 660);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);
        frame.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        frame.setBounds(10, 10, 1260, 660);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Don't use a null layout**. Don't use setBounds(). A `JScrollPane` will not work when a null layout is used. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Scroll WILL work automatically when layout managers are used. The layout manager will set the size/location of your components. Of course you also need to add your panel to a JScrollPane and add the scroll pane to the frame.

Comment: but i want to define the components position myself can you please demonstrate

Comment: *"can you please demonstrate"* Stack Overflow is not a code generation machine, but the GUI can basically be created using a `GridLayout` for the buttons, in what looks well suited to a `JTabbedPane` for the categories, and either a `TitledBorder` for the title or a `JLabel` in the `PAGE_START` of a `BorderLayout` (with the tabbed pane(s) in the `CENTER`). Have a crack at implementing that & get back to us if you experience problems you cannot resolve with a little research.

Comment: *"I guess"* I recommend you put a hold on guessing for the moment. The above code suggests a lack of proficiency in it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make it scrollable you should you a JScrollPane, you can use this java doc for more information https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

Comment: I did but it is not working the way I want it to do you know where did I go wrong

Comment: A `JScrollPane` needs to get the preferred size of any panel or components it contains. `null` layouts make it impossible for the child components to know how big they need to be.